# .htaccess how to open files in subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i have many sitemap files for dynamic subdomains located in subdirectory:

- /sitemap/town1.xml for town1.mysite.com
- /sitemap/town2.xml for town2.mysite.com

How should I config .htaccess, that request will open file [/sitemap/town1.xml](http://town1.mysite.com/sitemap.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

After all, i came to this solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap.xml$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.site.com/sitemap/%1.xml [L,NC,P]
```